# Convergence properties of series $\sum (a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

I did Part I using Cauchy criterion for convergence.
I have no idea how to do Part II and III though.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

(II): First do it when $k=1$. There is a natural candidate for the derivative Then give an estimate of the difference between $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$ and $\sum_k k(b_k\sin(kx)+a_k\cos(kx))$, where $f$ is the sum of the Fourier series. The diea is similar for $k>1$.

(III) Justify the differentiation under the series.